# How to open Internet explorer from GUI while launching it from eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I have developed one GUI.In that when I click one button of GUI it should go to Internet Explorer.But when I launch this from Eclipse it is not directed to IE. I tried this from outside eclipse.That is working fine.Any setup is needed to open IE from GUI in eclipse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if your refer to this, but inside Eclipse if you go to the Window menu -> Web Browsers and select Internet Explorer shoul done it.